# Get SyntaxTree from TypeSyntax

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

Is there an easy way to get to the `SyntaxTree` of the document in which a specific `TypeSyntax` is defined?

I can get the `Identifier` property whenever the `TypeSyntax` is `IdentifierNameSyntax` but I still can't get a secure way to visit the `SyntaxTree` of the Type.

Update:

Here's what I currently have :

```
var right = exp.Right as ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax;
                    if (right != null) {
                        Compilation comp;
                        if ((comp = activeProject.GetCompilationAsync().Result) != null) {
                            bool cst = comp.ContainsSyntaxTree(right.Type.SyntaxTree);
                            var semanticModel = comp.GetSemanticModel(right.Type.SyntaxTree);
                            var typeInfo = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(right.Type);
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            //var c = comp.GetSemanticModel(comp);
                            //var model = c.GetTypeInfo(right.Type as TypeSyntax);
                            //var v = model.Type.DeclaringSyntaxReferences;
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read type info, you need to get the semantic model.

Call `SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(TypeSyntax)` to get the `SymbolInfo`, then read the [`DeclaringSyntaxReferences` property](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/ISymbol.cs,147) of the symbol.

Note that partial classes may have multiple symbols defined in multiple files.

Comment: @Chris: No; you're seeing .Net Reflection.  You need to get a `SemanticModel` from a `Compilation`, then call `SemanticModel.GetType(node)`

Comment: GetType still returns a .Net Reflection Type . A method that returns a TypeInfo object is GetTypeInfo. After a call to it i obtain a typeInfo object with two null public properties : ConvertedType = null and Type = null.

Comment: @Chris: http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Shared/Extensions/SemanticModelExtensions.cs,64

Comment: @Chris: Actually, on further thought, I think you need `GetSymbolInfo()` (`GetType()` returns the type of an expression such as a variable and will not work on an actual `TypeSyntax`, where you want the symbol that the node directly represents)

Comment: Just checked it out : with this i can indeed access the DeclaringSyntaxRefernce